# Multiple languages in Apple Numbers

Tags: localization, translation, iwork-numbers

I need to reformat a whole bunch of dates from `1/1` to `Wednesday 1/1` in the English column and `Mercredi 1/1` in the French.

But it seems like in Apple Numbers (version 6.2.1) you can only select one language for the whole document.

Is that really the case?

Comment: Yes, this is similar situation with all spreadsheet programs. As a workaround you might be able to format the colums as text.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have apple numbers to test, in Excel you can use a custom number format to specify language of number format.

e.g. for French you can write `[$-fr-FR]dddd m/d`

[image]